# Pivot table loses "heat map" colouring when exporting to csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, styling

This code (using seaborn) is intended to give values in a pandas generated pivot table different shades of blue according to their value and colour null values red:

```
mapping = sns.light_palette("blue", as_cmap=True)

df.style.background_gradient(cmap=mapping)
df.style.highlight_null(null_color='red')
```

However this doesn't have any effect on the table whatsoever. What am I missing here?

**Edited** To repair spelling/formatting errors

Comment: CSV files are text-only files. They do not support gradients, backgrounds, etc.

Comment: Okay thank you - this has been the cause of a lot of stress